# Binding Ember.TextField value to another Controller's property

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js

My index.html says:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="loggedout">
 <label>Username: </label>{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="your username"  valueBinding="App.LoggedoutController.username"}}<br />
 <label>Password: </label>{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="your password" valueBinding="App.LoggedoutController.password" type="password"}}<br />
 <br /><button {{action login}}>Login</button>
 </script>
```

The action goes to my router which redirects to my controller

```
 App.LoggedoutController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    username: '',
    password: '',
    isError: false,

    tryLogin: function() {
      console.log("InController: launched");
      var username = this.get("username");
      console.log("Check:" + username);
      ....
```

but Check is empty.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfabs/KsNaX/)

Comment: try valueBinding="App.router.LoggedoutController.username" orelse post a simple fiddle...

Comment: its not working. i hoped to get this solved without a fiddle. how can I check if I am in the rigth view? probably this.get('username') doesnt work.

Comment: oops it shud be "App.router.loggedOutController.username" (camelCased), this.get("username") is correct...

Comment: added fiddle. still not working

Comment: you shud then probably accept my answer instead of someone who posted answer based on my comments...you're welcome by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path App.LoggedoutController.username in your valueBinding is wrong. With App.LoggedoutController you are referencing the class you have defined by using Ember.Controller.extend(). Probably somewhere in your code you have used App.intialize(). This causes the Controller to be instantiated by the framework. Then you can retrieve it by using the path App.router.loggedoutController.

Remember: Names of instances start always with a small letter. Classes alway with a big one.

So the solution is: Use valueBindung="App.router.loggedoutController.username"

**Edit**: Your fiddle is not working, since you did not link the required ember libraries. Look at the left in 'Add Resources'. There you have to specify the right URLs for Ember and Handlebars JS files.

Answer (score 2):

If you call "connectOutlet" in your router then you don't have to worry about the App.loggedOutController bit (from an MVC point of view it's better to keep the "App." out of templates as much as possible).

```
      loggedOut: Ember.Route.extend
      route: '/signin'
      connectOutlets: (router) ->
        router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet 'loggedOut'
```

Then in your template you can simply have:

```
{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="your username"  valueBinding="username"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the camelCasing & using the `router` keyword, you did not have router int he binding...

You used 
`App.outController.username` 
instead of 
`App.router.outController.username`

This is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtXtM/)